# Can't make static reference to non-static method ( Android getApplicationContext() )

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-context, static

I have been storing a global variable that's needed across Activities in my Android app by using a subclass of android.app.Application as explained by Soonil (in [How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)).

The approach looks like this:

```
class MyApp extends Application {

    private String myState;

    public String getState(){
    return myState;
    }
        public void setState(String s){
        myState = s;
    }
}

class Blah extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    ...
    MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
    String state = appState.getState();
    ...
    }
}
```

Up to this point, this approach has worked fine for accessing the global variable from any of my Activities.  But today using the same approach, I got the following error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext()
from the type ContextWrapper
```

The key difference from before is that the new Activity is actually a Fragment (SherlockFragmentActivity, to be precise).

Any ideas why can't I access appState as I have before, and is there a good workaround?

Many thanks.

---

EDIT: Good catch, Matt B.  It turns out the place I'm actually calling getApplicationContext() is inside another class.  Here's the calling point:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    public static class AccountListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
        MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, as noted below, the error went away when I changed the call to

```
MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Can we see the actual code you have in your activity that extends SherlockFragmentActivity? EDIT: I tried `Application appState = ((Application)getApplicationContext());` in my `SherlockFragmentActivity` and it compiles just fine.

Comment: I don't see where in this code sample you are attempting to make a static reference to that method. Are you sure you posted the correct line(s)?

Comment: can you then please mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getActivity().getApplication()
```

should work just fine.

You first need a reference to activity, then to application

The difference is that you are now calling this function from a Fragment (even though you named it "Activity") instead of an Activity

Comment: According to his question he says it is a SherlockFragmentActivity. If he actually means SherlockFragment, then your answer may be correct.

Comment: "new Activity is actually a Fragment (SherlockFragmentActivity, to be precise)."
I understand that he named his fragment "SherlockFragmentActivity"

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have cleared the error!  To be clear though, do you know why do I need to add the getActivity() call in this case (from inside a SherlockFragmentActivity), but not previously (from inside a normal Activity)?

Comment: Well for one you are naming your `Fragment` an Activity, which is confusing. You shouldn't have the word Activity in the name of a class that is not have the base class of `Activity`.

Comment: The fragment code is from a github repository (http://code.google.com/p/sherlock-demo/source/browse/#git%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fexample%2Fandroid%2Fsherlockdemo).  I also found the use of the term Activity a little confusing - but otherwise, the code seems like it will work :) .